# Free file attachment to editor (alternative of JCE file manager plugin)

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, plugin, file-upload, jce

As you know, JCE file manager is not free.

So, I am after a free plugin or component that can attach files (pdf,doc,zip, ...) to an article, but it must provide easy access from editor, like file manager of JCE.

Also I need that this component supports drag&drop files option.
Is there any free plugin/component that can do it?

(also it should be compatible with joomla 3.x)

Comment: Have you checked the Joomla Extensions Directory or even tried Google for this?

Comment: I searched but I could not find, also I think,maybe by searching alot in google, we can find an answer,but SE can be used for canonical answers usually, that other users can find it easily.

Comment: Phoca Download - Component and Plugin. Not sure about drag & drop, though.

Comment: There are a few tools that I think can do this e.g. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/article-elements/articles-summary/22187 but I don't know any free ones. The Joomla 3.5 media manager may help enable this? Joomla 3.5 is scheduled to be released very soon.

Answer (score 1):

What you think about free Joomla attachment comp ?  http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/attachments  I have used it before and its very good.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE editor is free, included in the Joomla core and supports drag and drop since Joomla 3.5.0.